# How to get translator base_dir from a URI in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Helle ZF2 Guru! Normally we get the zf2 translation file from a directory in Appliction module.config.php like this:   `'base_dir' => DIR . '/../language'` .
Is it possible to get it from a Uri?

```
Application module.config.php:
    'translator' => array(
             'locale' => 'en_US',
             'translation_file_patterns' => array(
                 array(
                     'type'     => 'gettext',
                      'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',//http://example.com/
                     'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
```

Why this is important?
Correct me if I am wrong! In a multilingual application, language files are static files and for a real world application any static files better be on cloud like `AWS CloudFront or CDON` for better performance of Application and longer caching period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this way is possible and I think it's not interresting to have this file outside the App directory because it's a part of your PHP software which will be interpreted and "compiled" by your web server at each HTTP request.

It's interresting for a JSON file downloaded by the navigator with AJAX request for example because the navigator will store the file in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to determine what is the current language in `application.config.php`:

```
define ('SITE_LANG', ...);
```

In our case it was simply the first two letters of the path:
www.site.com/en/...

Then in `module.config.php`:

```
'translator' => [
        'locale' => SITE_LANG,
        'translation_file_patterns' => [
            [
                'type' => 'phparray',
                'base_dir' => 'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/',
                'pattern' =>  '%s/Zend_Validate.php',
            ],
```

and it did the trick.

Comment: Interesting! But language files are still located in the same sever.

Comment: Should they be somewhere else?

Comment: That is the question! Normally, the language files located either under the Application dir or under vender/framework/resources/languages/. Can the language files be on the other domain?Fx base_dir=>'http://example.com/',

Comment: I don't think so. They are an essential part of application. They are not like CSS files or images.